# Python. Random letter from specific word

Tags: python

Im using python and i want to make a hangman game, ive made most of it. Player 1 writes a word in and then the Player 2 is going to guess what word it is by writing letter after letter, you have a total of 7 tries. The only thing i need now i something that can pick a random letter from the word that Player 2 is going to guess. When the player reaches below 3 tries or something like that. I am really new to coding and i dont know much for example i tried: if tries < 3: print(random.letter 'wordmaking') where wordmaking is the name of the import and word that Player 1 put in. Lets say youre playing hangman with a friend and you cant find out what word or letters he used. there will be a code that gives you a letter that has not been guessed for example: Guess word: _ _ _ _ You have 4 tries left
lets say the word was D E S K and he typed the letter G, the tries left would go down to 3 and the game would type Guess word: D _ _ _ You have 3 tries left. It added a letter when he reached below a certain point of tries as a hint. like in draw it, only that they give u hint when there is less time left.

Comment: hint: [`random.choice('string')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) will return a random letter from `'string'`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Are you looking to provide Player 2 a hint if they have fewer than three tries left?  Then it might be more helpful to pick a letter that hasn't been guessed yet?

Comment: @John thats what i ment, but i learnt coding this monday and i really suck at it.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> some_word = 'wordmaking'
>>> choice(some_word)
'i'
>>> choice(some_word)
'k'
>>> choice(some_word)
'i'
>>> choice(some_word)
'g'
```

Comment: not like that, but the word "wordmaking" could be any word, it could be dog, human, desk, pencil anything.

Answer (score 0):

would that work for what you are trying to do?

```
import random

tries=0 #iterator initiation
if tries<=3:
    letter=random.choice("thewordyouwannaselectlettersfrom")
    print(letter)

else:
    tries+=1
    continue
```

Comment: print("Skriv eit ord her:")
wordmaking = input()
guessed = []
wrong = []
tries = 7
while tries > 0:
    out = ""
    for letter in wordmaking:
        if letter in guessed:
            out = out + letter
        else:
            out = out + " _ "
    if out == wordmaking:
        break
    print("Gjett en bokstav i ordet:", out)
    print(tries, "forsøk igjen")


    guess = input()

    if guess in guessed or guess in wrong:
        print("Bokstaven er allerede gjettet på:", guess)
    elif guess in wordmaking:
        print("Yay")
        guessed.append(guess)
    else:

Comment: print("Nope")
        tries = tries - 1
        wrong.append(guess)
    print()
else:
    tries+=1
if tries:
    print("Du gjettet", wordmaking)
else:
    print("Du klarte ikke å gjette", wordmaking)

Comment: @daffenl - put your code in the body of your question, and format it with the 'code sample' feature - that's what you should generally do when you have a lengthy volume of code to show.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't help but write a hangman:

```
import random

# take input for the word of player 1
target = input('Player 1 word: ')

# set guess to empty, but same length as 'target'
guess = '_'*len(target)
tries = 0

while (guess != target) and (tries < 3):
    # take input of player 2
    s = input('Now: "' + guess + '"; Player 2 can guess: ')

    # if guessed input is longer than 1 character, skip it
    if len(s) > 1:
        print('only 1 character allowed at a time')
        continue 

    # update guess with guessed letter if it hits
    guess = ''.join(s if target[i] == s else guess[i] for i in range(len(target)))

    # test if there were any correct guesses, otherwise tries += 1
    if not any(target[i] == s for i in range(len(target))):
        tries+=1

# print result after exiting loop
print('Player {} WINS: word was {}'.format('2' if tries < 2 else '1', target))
```

Comment: if for example you have 3 tries left on the hangman to guess the word the module autmaticly writes in a letter for you as a hint